Excel for M365: calling the StockHistory function in VBA code makes the XLSM unable to be saved
I was testing calling the StockHistory function from VBA (available only in Microsoft 365 versions of Excel) and I noticed that afterwards Excel started complaining about the workbook being corrupted and completely failed at being able to save the workbook once more. I initially thought the issue was caused by the updating of data in the workbook I was doing but after having removed all code apart the call to the StockHistory function I realized that it is the call itself that is destabilizing Excel. Below the stripped-down function to reproduce the problem. Force multiple executions (at least two) of the function by clicking CRTL+ALT+F9 and then try to save the workbook.
Public Function GetData(ticker As String) As String

    Dim data As Variant
    data = Application.WorksheetFunction.StockHistory(ticker, Date - 10, Date, 0, 0, 1)
    
    GetData = ticker

End Function

To test the function insert in a cell something like the following:
=GetData("MSFT")

My Excel should be the latest available via M365 (Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO - Version 2406 Build 16.0.17726.20078 - 64-bit).

I can repro this using exactly the code you have supplied. Wow, this is terrible.

Did you report the bug to Microsoft?

Yes, I did just now

The weird thing is that after a first execution of the function you are still able to save the workbook. It is after a further execution of the function that the thing breaks completely.

Workaround: Have a cell containing the formula =STOCKHISTORY("amd",TODAY()-10,TODAY()) somewhere in  the *.xlsm workbook, maybe in a hidden sheet. After that the problem should be gone. Background: The function STOCKHISTORY stores data of content type application/vnd.ms-excel.rdrichvalue+xml in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2017/richdata. This content type and namespace get set in workbook when the function got evaluated as a cell formula but not when called by VBA.

Hm, indeed, GetData = ticker is definitely wrong and should be GetData = data, yet it's still very unexpected that this behavior occurs then.

Wrong? What is being returned from a function is up to its creator and depends on its intended use. Never heard that after getting some data, if you don't return it an application will crash :D

Same problem (and successful fix as rec'd by @AxelRichter), using Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2405 Build 16.0.17628.20006) 64-bit)

I have also noticed same behavior, and correction, with OP's version. Also, it seems that after entering the formula from @AxelRichter in some cell, it can subsequently be deleted and the workbook can be saved.

@RonRosenfeld and AxelRichter I AM coming from that way of calling the stockhistory formula. so I know far too well how to otherwise make it work. Still I've never seen such a misbehavior when moving a function call from a sheet into vba code. –

Have you raised your issue in here Microsoft_User_Voice_Feedback_Portal

@MayukhBhattacharya I sent a detailed problem report directly from excel

Have they contacted you, may be its too late, do raise a ticket using the Quick Assist app from Windows it will be faster. I had some issues sometime earlier, used that app, resolved within few by the MS Support team!

no but I suppose today is Sunday also for the office product group and they might not need to contact me if they can reproduce the problem themselves

Another interesting point: The file can be successfully saved as a .xlsb file.

@RonRosenfeld interesting. Xlsb is a binary format (not OpenXML). I was not aware of the fact that macros can be saved in xlsb files.

@whatever Before OpenXML, there was xls, xlsb, xla, xlt.  Different format.
